# Creating an instance of a React-Native bridged iOS class

Tags: swift, reactjs, react-native, wrapper

I am writing a react native app that bridges and uses Swift classes, I have the bridging working and I can call functions on the class I have created. I am trying to make it so the I have to create an instance of the swift class in react-js, but I'm not sure on how to do this.

Here are my code examples:

Swift Class:

```
import Foundation

@objc(Torch)
class Torch: NSObject
{

  @objc static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {return true}

  @objc var isOn = false

  @objc func turnOn() {
    isOn = true
  }
  @objc func turnOff() {
    isOn = false
  }
  @objc func getTorchStatus(_ callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) {
      callback([NSNull(), isOn])
  }
}
```

Objective C class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(Torch,NSObject)

    RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(requiresMainQueueSetup)
    RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(turnOn)
    RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(turnOff)
    RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getTorchStatus: (RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)

@end
```

Bridging-Header:

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
```

React-Native code:

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
var Torch = NativeModules.Torch;
Torch.turnOn()
Torch.getTorchStatus((error, isOn) => {
   console.log(isOn)
 });
```

When I run the app, it sets the value of the torch to true, and then prints it value via getting its state.

If I do this again

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
var Torch = NativeModules.Torch;
Torch.turnOn()
Torch.getTorchStatus((error, isOn) => {
   console.log(isOn)
 });

var NewTorch = NativeModules.Torch;
NewTorch.getTorchStatus((error, isOn) => {
   console.log(isOn)
 });
```

This prints the same value as before, like NewTorch is the same instance as Torch. I was wondering how you create a new instance of Torch so it has its own state instead of a shared state. Or if this is even possible and I need to create a class to manage the instances within swift.

Any help on this would be great, thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The bridge is exposing torch class along with its methods that is running on background of react native and all it does is exposes its methods. Maybe bridging new class/method that returns new instance of Torch class can do the trick.

Comment: How would I achieve that with my current setup? Im pretty new to react native and bridging it to iOS/Android. Or would it be best to have a TorchManager class that handles the various instances?

Comment: Create class like you did with torch. Create method inside new class that creates instance of Torch and returns it (probably similar to getTorchstatus). Similar to RCT_EXTERN_MODULE for Torch, do same with new class and RCT_EXTERN_METHOD for the new method. Not sure if it does the trick but give it a try.